# Classifier training failed: 'Only one class.'

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-cover, land-classification

I am new to Google Earth Engine and am trying to classify landcover. I keep getting the error of "Classifier training failed: 'Only one class.'." However, I have multiple classes.

```
var classes = water.merge(vegetation).merge(Mangrove); 
var bands = ['B5','B6','B4','NDVI','MNDWI','SR','GCVI']
var image = compositeNew.select(bands).clip(geometry)


    var samples = image.sampleRegions({
       collection: classes, // Set of geometries selected for training
    properties: ['landcover'], // Label from each geometry
    scale: 30 // Make each sample the same size as Landsat pixel
    }).randomColumn('random'); // creates a column with random numbers
    

var split = 0.7; // Roughly 80% for training, 20% for testing.
var training = samples.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split)); //Subset training data
var testing = samples.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split)); //Subset testing data


//Print these variables to see how much training and testing data you are using
    print('Samples n =', samples.aggregate_count('.all'));
    print('Training n =', training.aggregate_count('.all'));
    print('Testing n =', testing.aggregate_count('.all'));


    var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(100,5).train({ 
    features: training.select(['B5','B6','B4','NDVI','MNDWI','SR','GCVI', 'landcover']), //Train using bands and landcover property
    classProperty: 'landcover', //Pull the landcover property from classes
    inputProperties: bands
    });



    var validation = testing.classify(classifier);
    var testAccuracy = validation.errorMatrix('landcover', 'classification');
    print('Validation error matrix RF: ', testAccuracy);
    print('Validation overall accuracy RF: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());


    var classifiedrf = image.select(bands) // select the predictors
                      .classify(classifier); // .classify applies the Random Forest
                      



//Add classification to map
Map.addLayer (classes, {min: 0, max: 2, palette:['green','blue','red']}, 'Mangrove Extent 2019');
```

The link to my code is: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a6570039fd9225cb920ac8368c56479f

Comment: Edit your question and add the relevant part of the code as text. The link require you to log in

Answer (score 0):

You've clipped your images to `geometry` but there's no `vegetation` points inside that geometry, and you've masked off all the off-shore water pixels with the NDVImask, so the only pixels that aren't null valued are the class=0 ones.

[image]